# Midrash about Abraham , Moon and 14 generations?

Tags: abraham, moon

I heard one rabbi tell a story connecting Abraham , and cycles of the moon and generations it takes to David from Abraham!

Is anyone familiar with this story and where can i find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Shemot Rabbah 15:26](http://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.15.26).  I've quoted and translated it for you below:

> דבר אחר: החדש הזה לכם, הדא הוא דכתיב (תהילים עב, ז): יפרח בימיו צדיק ורוב שלום עד בלי ירח, עד שלא הוציא הקדוש ברוך הוא את ישראל ממצרים, ברמז הודיע להם, שאין המלכות בא להם עד שלשים דור, שנאמר: החדש הזה לכם ראש חדשים, החדש שלשים יום, ומלכות שלכם שלשים דור. הלבנה בראשון של ניסן מתחלת להאיר, וכל שהיא הולכת מאירה עד חמישה עשר ימים, ודסקוס שלה מתמלא, ומחמישה עשר עד שלשים אור שלה חסר, בשלשים אינה נראית. כך ישראל, חמישה עשר דור מן אברהם ועד שלמה. אברהם התחיל להאיר, שנאמר (ישעיה מא, ב): מי העיר ממזרח צדק יקראהו לרגלו. בא יצחק אף הוא האיר, שנאמר (תהלים צז, א): אור זרוע לצדיק. בא יעקב והוסיף אור, שנאמר (ישעיה י, יז): והיה אור ישראל לאש. ואחר כך, יהודה פרץ חצרון רם עמינדב נחשון שלמון בועז עובד ישי דוד. כיון שבא שלמה, נתמלא דיסקוס של לבנה, שנאמר (דה"א כט, כג): וישב שלמה על כסא ה' למלך. וכי יוכל אדם לישב בכסאו של הקדוש ברוך הוא, מי שנאמר בו (דניאל ז, ט): כרסיה שביבין די נור?! אלא מה הקדוש ברוך הוא שולט מסוף העולם ועד סופו, ושולט בכל המלכים, שנאמר (תהלים קלח, ד): יודוך ה' כל מלכי ארץ. כן של שלמה, מסוף העולם ועד סופו, שנאמר (דה"ב ט, כג-כד): וכל מלכי הארץ מבקשים את פני שלמה וגו'. והמה מביאים איש מנחתו, לכך נאמר: וישב שלמה על כסא ה' למלך. הקדוש ברוך הוא לבושו הוד והדר, ונתן לשלמה הוד מלכות, שנאמר (דה"א שם, כה): ויתן עליו הוד מלכות. בכסאו של הקדוש ברוך הוא, כתיב (יחזקאל א, י): ודמות פניהם פני אדם ופני אריה. ובשלמה כתיב (מ"א ז, כט): ועל המסגרות אשר בין השלבים אריות בקר. וכתוב אחד אומר ( שם שם, לג): כמעשה אופן המרכבה. בכסאו של הקדוש ברוך הוא אין דבר רע נוגע, שנאמר (תהלים ה, ה): לא יגורך רע. ובשלמה כתיב (מ"א ה, יח): אין שטן ואין פגע רע. הקדוש ברוך הוא עשה ששה רקיעים, ובשביעי יושב. ובכסאו של שלמה כתיב ( שם י, יט): שש מעלות לכסא ויושב במעלה השביעית, הרי נתמלא דיסקוס של לבנה, ומשם התחילו המלכים פוחתין והולכין. (דה"א ג, י): ובן שלמה רחבעם, ובן רחבעם אביה, ובנו אסא, יהושפט, יהורם, אחזיהו, יואש, אמציהו, עוזיה, יותם, אחז, יחזקיה, מנשה, אמון, יאשיהו, יהויקים. כיון שבא צדקיהו, דכתיב (ירמיה נב, יא): ואת עיני צדקיהו עור, חסר אורה של לבנה. וכל אותן השנים, אף על פי שהיו ישראל חוטאין, היו האבות מתפללין עליהן, ועושין שלום בין ישראל למקום, שנאמר (תהלים עב, ג): ישאו הרים שלום לעם, ואין הרים אלא אבות, שנאמר (מיכה ו, ב): שמעו הרים את ריב ה'. ועד מתי היו האבות מתפללין עליהן? עד שאבד צדקיהו את עיניו וחרב בית המקדש, שנאמר (תהלים שם, ז): ורב שלום עד בלי ירח, עד שלשים דור שהיה לישראל מן המלכות, מן אותה שעה ועד עתה. מי עושה שלום לישראל? ה', שנאמר (במדבר ו, כו): ישא ה' פניו אליך וישם לך שלום:
>
> Another interpretation: This month shall be for you (Ex 12:2), this is what's written (Ps 72:7): In his days the righteous will flourish and much peace until the moon is no more. While God had not yet taken Israel out of Egypt, he alluded to them that Kingship would not be theirs for 30 generations, as it's written (Ex 12:2): This month shall be for you the beginning of months. A month is 30 days, and your Kingship will be in 30 generations.  The moon begins to shine at the beginning of the month of Nisan, and it increases its shine and waxes for 15 days, but from the 15th until the 30th it wanes in intensity, and on the 30th it is no longer seen.  So too for Israel: 15 generations from Abraham to Shlomo.  Abraham began to shine, as it says (Is 41:2): Who raised up one from the east, at whose steps victory attends? Then Yitshak also shone, ... then Yaakov, ... Yehuda, Perets, Chetsron, Ram, Aminadav, Nachson, Salmon, Boaz, Oved, Yishai, David.  Once Shlomo arrived, the moon's disc had become full, as it says (1 Chr 29:23): Shlomo sat on the throne of the Lord as king...

The midrash describes the glory of God and Shlomo's kingdom, then continues:

> And the son of Shlomo was Rekhavam, and Rekhavam's son was Aviya, and his son Asa, Yehoshafat, Yehoram, Akhazyahu, Yoash, Amatsyahu, Uzziya, Yotam, Akhaz, Yekhizkiya, Menashe, Amon, Yoshiyahu, Yehoyakim.  Once Tsidkiyahu came, as it's written (Jer 52:11): He put out the eyes of Tsidkiyahu, the moon's light diminished.  All those years, even though Israel was sinning, the Forefathers prayed for them and made peace between them and God... until when did the Forefathers pray for them?  Until Tsidkiyahu lost his eyes and the Temple was destroyed, as it's said (Ps 72:7): And much peace until the moon is no more, that is, until 30 generations that Israel had kingship.  From that moment until now, who makes peace for Israel?  God, as it's said (Num 6:26): May God look favourably upon you and give you peace.